# Divide a form of checkboxes into two or three columns with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a form full of Bootstrap checkboxes. However, I want to have it plit into two or three columns, so not to take lots of lines.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    {section name=x loop=$records}
            {section name=y loop=$records[x]}
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name={$records[x][y].prefkey} {if   $records[x][y].prefval == "on"}checked{/if}>
                    {$records[x][y].prefkey}
                </label>
              </div>
            {/section}
    {/section}
</div>
```

Please any help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap your `<div class="checkbox"></div>` into div with class `col-*-4` to get it 3 columns or `col-*-6` to get 2 columns.

[**Reference to docs**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-intro)

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/g7aQM/)**

**UPDATE:**

add the following css to avoid problem with jumbotron:

```
.jumbotron{
    overflow:hidden
}
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/g7aQM/1/)**

Comment: I did what you told me, but now the jumbotron doesn't cover all the checkboxes, that's bizarre !! This is what I've changed: <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name={$records[x][y].prefkey} {if $records[x][y].prefval == "on"}checked{/if}>
                        {$records[x][y].prefkey}
                    </label>
                  </div>
                 </div>